# how to update main registration table and secondary multicheckbox populated table?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have a registration form with different input fields one of them being a multi checkbox so that the user can decide what countries he wants to receive information from. This last one is created like this:

```
$pais = $this->createElement('multiCheckbox', 'pais');
$pais->setLabel('Pais\es: ');
$pais->addMultioption('1', 'Argentina');
$pais->addMultioption('2', 'Espa?a');
$pais->addMultioption('3', 'Brasil');
$pais->addMultioption('4', 'USA');
$pais->addMultioption('5', 'Italia');
$this->addElement($pais);
```

In my UserController I have the following action to update the table 'users':

```
public function createAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = 'Create User';
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Users.php';
    $userForm = new Form_User();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if ($userForm->isValid($_POST)) {
            $userModel = new Model_User();
            $userMode->createUser(
                $userForm->getValue('email'),
                $userForm->getValue('password'),
                $userForm->getValue('url'),
                $userForm->getValue('responsable'),
                $userForm->getValue('role')
            );
        return $this->_forward('list');
        }
    }
$userForm->setAction('/user/create');
$this->view->form = $userForm;
}
```

which of course, right now is not contemplating the multicheckbox populatedn$pais variable, nor here nor in the model:

```
class Model_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract 
{

protected $_name = 'users';

public function createUser($email, $password, $url, $responsable, $role)
{
    // create a new row
        $rowUser = $this->createRow();
        if($rowUser) {
            // update the row values
            $rowUser->email = $email;
            $rowUser->password = md5($password);
            $rowUser->url = $url;
            $rowUser->responsable = $responsable;
            $rowUser->role = $role;
            $rowUser->save();
            //return the new user
            return $rowUser;
        } else {
        throw new Zend_Exception("El usuario no se ha podido crear!");
            }
    }
}
```

I have also a 'pais' table, which contains the 5 different countries, and I'm working on a separate model for 'users_has_pais' which is the table I created in the workbench for this purpose...but I'm not getting any results with what I'm doing right now. Can someone point me in the right path to get to update 'users_has_pais' at the same time that I update the 'users' table?

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone with good advice on this.

EDIT: this is the [db model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWtQL.png) in case anyone needs it to figure out what I'm saying

EDIT2:

```
    public function createAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = 'Create User';
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Users.php';
    $userForm = new Form_User();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if ($userForm->isValid($_POST)) {
            $userModel = new Model_User();
            $user = $userModel->createUser(
                    $userForm->getValue('email'),
                    $userForm->getValue('password'),
                    $userForm->getValue('url'),
                    $userForm->getValue('responsable'),
                    $userForm->getValue('role')
            );
            $paises = $this->getRequest()->getParam('pais');
            $userId = intval($user['id']);

            require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/UserHasPais.php';
            $paisesModel = new Model_UsersHasPais();
            $paisesModel->updateUserPais($userId, $paises);

            return $this->_forward('index');
        }
    }
```

and users_has_pais model:

```
class Model_UsersHasPais extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
```

{
    protected $_name = 'users_has_pais';

```
public function updateUserPais($id, array $paises)
{
    $row = ($r = $this->fetchRow(array('users_id = ?' => $id))) ? $r : $this->createRow();

    foreach($paises as $pais){
        $row->users_id = $id;
        $row->pais_id = $pais;
        $row->save();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create user row first, and use it's ID when creating rows for 'user_has_pais'. A pseudo-code is below:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = 'Create User';
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Users.php';
    $userForm = new Form_User();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if ($userForm->isValid($_POST)) {
            $userModel = new Model_User();
           $newUserRow = $userMode->createUser(
                $userForm->getValue('email'),
                $userForm->getValue('password'),
                $userForm->getValue('url'),
                $userForm->getValue('responsable'),
                $userForm->getValue('role')
            );

           $user_id = newUserRow->id;

           $checkBoxValues = $userForm->getValue('pais');
           // $checkBoxValues should be an array where keys are option names and
           // values are values. If checkbox is not checked, than the value = 0;
           // At this moment I'm not 100% sure of the real nature of the 'pais' value,
           // but this is only an example. 

           // I also assume that the values of the checkboxfields correspond to IDs in 
           // 'pais'.

           foreach ($checkBoxValues as $key => $pais_id) {
                    if (intval(pais_id) > 0) {
                        // if language was checked

                        // do insert into user_has_pais having $pais_id and $user_id.   

                    }
           }

        return $this->_forward('list');
        }
    }
$userForm->setAction('/user/create');
$this->view->form = $userForm;
}
```

You could also put all of this in *transaction* if you want. 
Hope this helps, or at least you point you in the right direction.

Comment: am trying with something like that but it's only adding one record, Check the Edited source and let me know if you see where my logic fails please.

Comment: @la_f0ka. Your updateUserPais method creates only one row and the foreach loop inside just updates this row. createRow should be within the foreach loop.